# Reply to an email asking how I am and do I still want to work there

Tags: communication, recruitment

Hi can anyone tell me how to reply this email. Should I be honest about how okay I am, or keep it professional? Wording would be helpful. Thanks.

Hi xxxxx

How are you?

I've just seen the below email.  I'm sorry that you have decided to stop working in (this capacity) at project xxxxxxx.  I wanted to check in with you to make sure you were okay and to see if you wished to remain on our list however not work at xxxxx.  We certainly have a lot more projects now in your local area with the new services.

I look forward to hearing from you.

Best wishes

Kind regards

Xxxxxx
Recruitment Manager

Comment: We cannot tell you "how ok" you are, or what part of "being ok" you want to share with others. Generally speaking, "stay professional" is never wrong. Seems like a genuine question, just reply according to what you prefer... stay on their list or not.

Comment: This seems hard to answer in general without knowing what kind of position you are in.

Comment: The position is Support Worker. I resigned from a project because I couldn't cope with the gross negligence of the Manager , and now Recruitment wants to know if I am okay and whether I want to work at another project.

Comment: Ignore the "how are you" question and just answer the question about whether you want to work on another project. That's what they actually want to know.

Answer (score 3):

"How are you" in English is usually social ritual rather than being a serious inquiry. In this case you can give a ritual response such as "I'm doing fine, thanks for asking", or give a meaningful but terse response ("I'm feeling better...." or whatever), or you can ignore that question completely.

In a business letter I'd generally ignore it -- it doesn't actually mean much more than setting a friendly tone for the letter. They aren't you doctor or your close friends. They are "not" expecting a detailed report on your status.

They want to know if you are interested in coming back. Answer that part politely, with an appropriate level of enthusiasm if you do want the work. That's all you need to do.

Comment: Thanks. I have met the Recruitment Manager and we got along well, so I was wondering whether I should reply in a meaningful way to her enquiry about "how I am",  She does know some shit went down at the service I resigned from, which would have caused me some stress, but I think I will keep it strictly professional.

Comment: Generally, assume it's just formal ritual unless the person knows you and your situation very well and actually cares. I'm recovering from a medical emergency at the moment, but I would assume that the other person is ***not*** really interested in all the details unless they ask much more explicitly and directly. The most I would tell most folks in writing is "recovering, but not quite ready to go back to work yet."